# Styling octopress image layout (eg images all in a row)

Tags: jekyll, octopress

Any tips on styling image layout with the `{%img ... %}` plugin?

I'm ok with `left` and `right` but I'd really like to have all images in a row vertically for example and can't quiet figure out how to style things.

I thought perhaps add a `<div class="right">` around a bunch on `{% img ... %}` but that seems to mess with the HTML too much.

Thanks in advance for any pointers

ps, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663530/how-to-arrange-images-in-a-grid-in-octopress-using-markdown?rq=1) but it didn't answer my question exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In markdown, you can write tables using the following syntax

```
-----------------
|   A   |   B   |
| :---: | :---: |
|   C   |   D   |
-----------------
```

The two points on each side of the horizontal lines define the alignment of your cells:

- **centered**: `:--:`
- **left**: `:---`
- **right**: `---:`

You can use as many dashes as you want in the middle.

I used this technique to align images as a table in [this blog post](http://blog.alestanis.com/2013/02/04/octopress-and-the-twilight-color-scheme/) (search for "Nil" inside). It looks like this:

[image: aligned images with markdown table]

using this code:

```
| Nil | Inline / list | Table |
| :---: | :---: | :---: |
| {% img /images/2013-02-04-nil.png 36 92 Nil line numbers %} | {% img /images/2013-02-04-inline.png 62 92 Inline line numbers %} | {% img /images/2013-02-04-table.png 72 92 Table line numbers %} |
```

Comment: Note that standard Markdown does not include tables. You'll need a Markdown extension such as MultiMarkdown to create tables.